# Ruby not incrementing number

Tags: ruby

I wrote code to find how many operations a number required under the Collatz Conjecture. However, my operations variable doesn't seem to be incrementing.

My code is:

```
puts "Please input a number"
number = gets.chomp
number = number.to_i
operations = 0
modulo = number % 2
while number =! 1
    if modulo == 0
        number = number / 2
        operations = operations + 1
    elsif modulo =! 0 && number =! 1
        number = number * 3
        number = number += 1
        operations = operations + 2
    else
        puts "Uh oh, something went wrong."
    end
end
puts "It took #{operations} operations!"
```

I am running this code on https://www.repl.it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I think @Wickramaranga, will answer your question. You just have some syntax error on you code. (e.g. [elseif => elsif], [number = number += 1 => number += 1] ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's `elsif`; not `elseif` (I edited that in your question). And unequal sign is `!=`; not `=!`. But that has a somewhat different meaning. (i.e.: `number =! 1` means `number = !1`)

In the 12th line, what is `number = number += 1`? I think you meant `number += 1` or `number = number + 1`.

Now, the code works. :)

Here's the final version.

```
puts "Please input a number"
number = gets.chomp
number = number.to_i
operations = 0
modulo = number % 2
while number != 1
    if modulo == 0
        number = number / 2
        operations = operations + 1
    elsif modulo != 0 && number != 1
        number = number * 3
        number = number + 1
        operations = operations + 2
    else
        puts "Uh oh, something went wrong."
    end
end
puts "It took #{operations} operations!"
```

Usage:

```
Please input a number
256
It took 8 operations!
```

An optimal solution using functions:

```
def collatz(n)
    if n % 2 == 0
        return n / 2
    else
        return 3*n + 1
    end
end
def chainLength(num)
    count = 1
    while num > 1
        count += 1
        num = collatz(num)
    end
    return count
end

puts "Please input a number"
number = gets.chomp
number = number.to_i
operations = chainLength(number)
puts "It took #{operations} operations!"
```

If you need more performance, read about *dynamic programming* and *memoization* techniques.

Comment: Thanks so much! Any ideas on how to optimize for speed?

Comment: @jBit Edited upon your request. Note that it's a hasty translation based on one of my old python code.

Comment: @jBit welcome. :D Feel free to mark as the answer. ;)